# php5 not being run as www-data

Tags: php, apache, configuration, usergroups

I have some files that I need php to service to a client. These files are owned by `www-data` as they should be, with permissions `644`. Access to these files is beig denied however, so I ran this little  script:

```
<?php
    echo shell_exec('whoami');
?>
```

which prints out `daemon`, thisis not the user that I want php running as.

Where in the php or apache configuration files can I set it so that php is run as user `www-data`?

Edit: I've seen this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/453811/how-to-configure-php-cli-on-linux-ubuntu-to-run-as-www-data), but I do not want to set up aliases, and I believe that only applies to running php scripts form the terminal.

Edit 2: php v5.6 with apache v2.4 on ubuntu 12.04LTS

Comment: What is your OS (try `uname -a`)? What is the output of your `phpinfo()`?

Comment: phpinfo is pretty long to post, are there any specific portions I should look at?

Comment: Under the apache2handler section, it does say `User/Group daemon(1)/1`

Comment: Check User/Group in your httpd.conf or in your Apache startup script.

Comment: Looks like you were right, there was a line in httpd.conf that set the user and group to daemon, thanks. Feel free to make an answer so I can accept it as best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user and group Apache is running as is set in httpd.conf with the [`User` and `Group` directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_unixd.html#user). Changing them to `www-data` should get you what you need.