# PHP: get_current_user() vs. exec('whoami')

Tags: php, apache, unix, xampp, chmod

***Short version of the question:***

What's the difference between
`get_current_user();` and `exec('whoami');` ?

***Long version of the question:***

1. I'm on a XAMPP Localhost on a Mac.
2. I'm using Apache, building a PHP
   based website in a folder (let's call it **folderxyz**) within the
   htdocs folder (var/www in some flavors of Linux+Apache).
3. I was playing around with a database connection,
   testing out PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION described here: [Link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059)

And I got this error:

> file_put_contents(**PDOErrors.txt**): failed to open stream: Permission
> denied...

So I did some sleuthing around and it seems that to fix this I need to change the `CHMOD` settings of file **PDOErrors.txt** to 777.

**However, my questions are about something else.** During this process I realized that I don't clearly understand the concept of `user` in Apache, PHP, and MySQL.

- The PHP manual says that `get_current_user()` *"Gets the name of the owner of the current PHP script"* [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php)
- The PHP manual says that `exec('whoami')` returns *"the username that owns the running php/httpd process"* [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#refsect1-function.exec-examples)
- When I use `get_current_user()`, I get my `firstnamelastname`, which is my account name on my Mac.
- When I use `exec('whoami')`, I get `daemon`.

**So...**

1. What's the relationship between `firstnamelastname` and `daemon` ?
2. What's the relationship between the *"the owner of the current PHP script"* and *"username that owns the running php/httpd process"* ?
3. Who needs permission to write to **PDOErrors.txt**? Is it `firstnamelastname` or `daemon` ?
4. Who needs permission to write to **PDOErrors.txt**? Is it Apache or PHP (or both) ?
5. Does the concept of a unix-like `root` account factor-in anywhere here ?

---

Edit: I updated this to reflect that it wasn't the **folderxyz** that I had to change CHMOD settings for. I had to change the settings for the file **PDOErrors.txt**

---

OP here: for future reference, I put up a parallel question for the Linux platform here (with an accompanying intuitive explanation of what's going on): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31389892/why-is-the-output-www-data-in-one-case-and-root-in-another

Update: That question was deleted as it was deemed to be a duplicate of this one (although that was for the Linux platform, and instead of `daemon` I was getting `www-data` after doing `echo exec('whoami');` ).

This is what I learned from asking this question in the Linux forum:

> the running process is different than the script. Yes, the process emerges from the script, but it's not the same thing. The script is owned by root, but the process is taken over by Apache and is run as www-data.

---

Overall conclusion: What I learned from this process is that **user** is supposed to be the Apache **daemon** (Mac localhost) or **www-data** (Linux on an internet server) and that I should be using `exec('whoami')` to determine this, and I shouldn't care too much about `get_current_user()` (which probably should have been named `get_current_owner()`).

Comment: I want to add for future reference, the following Stackoverflow answer explains why the Apache user shows up as `daemon` on a local machine, whereas as `www-data` on a public machine (i.e., usable by anyone on the internet). I looked at the settings in the Apache `httpd.conf` file in my local machine and the `user` and `group` settings were indeed set to `daemon`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063556/php5-not-being-run-as-www-data

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. `get_current_user()` (should) return the owner of the file, which is `firstnamelastname` in this case. There have been reported issues that this function is inconsistent between platforms however. As such, I would not trust its output. `daemon` is the user Apache is running as.
2. The owner of the PHP script is the user who owns the file itself according to the operating system. You can run `ls -la` in the directory your scripts are in to find the user and group the file belongs to.
3. Whichever user you're editing your scripts with needs to be able to write it, so most likely, `firstnamelastname` (`+rw`).
4. For the folder itself, you should have `+rx` (execute and read) for `daemon` and for the PHP file, `+r` (read). On my installation of XAMMP, they've done this by setting everything in `htdocs` as public readable, thus `daemon` can read it, but not write to it.
5. Mac has a root account that typically owns the `htdocs` or `www` directory. It fills the role of a traditional unix root user.

Here is some information on the file owners/groups and the process owner:

```
host:~$ ls -l /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs
drwxr-xr-x 3 root admin  4096 2015-01-01 00:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root admin  4096 2015-01-01 00:01 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 firstnamelastname admin   189 2015-01-31 20:45 index.php

host:~$ ps aux | grep httpd | head -n1    
daemon          45204   0.0  0.1  2510176  10328   ??  S    Tue11AM   0:01.38 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/httpd -k start -E /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
```

If you wanted to make a file writeable by the daemon user, you can create a new folder and name it as the owner with the group `admin` (so you can use it too), and give it `+rwx` for the user and group, with `+rx` for public:

```
host:~$ cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs
host:htdocs$ mkdir some_dir
host:htdocs$ chmod 775 some_dir
```