# Uniquely recognize Client on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, apache, google-chrome

I have apache installed on a windows laptop that is not connected to the internet.  The laptop has multiple user accounts.  Let's say that two of the user accounts are "Adam" and "Sally".  I have a project on localhost that needs to differentiate between the different Window's users via the Chrome browser.

I understand detecting the username through the browser directly is a gross security sandbox breach, but I don't care: I have complete control of the computer and the project is not web accessible, so there are no security concerns.  I'm willing to cheat in any way imaginable including building a custom .exe to help.  I just need to differentiate between the different accounts.  It doesn't need to be by username, but any alternative ID would need to persist for that given user.

I am asking for outside of the box thinking.

How can I create a page that I can open in Chrome that will say "Hi Adam" or "Hi Sally" or even "Hi -=[GUID]=-" without the visitor ever typing in their name/guid.

Comment: There is no way in JavaScript to identify the user. BUT you can probably write an extension that does it.

Comment: To be clear, it's not JavaScript that's stopping you, it's the DOM and browser security *protecting* you.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use something like [NW.js](https://nwjs.io/) or [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) instead of chrome for this so you don't have to sacrifice security.

Here's a picture of me running the nw.js sdk and loading just the demo page, bringing up the dev tools and retrieving my username.
[image: picture of NW.js development console]
Pretty straight forward. Follow node documentation and do whatever you'd like there.

You could have a [batch file that runs on startup](https://superuser.com/questions/15596/automatically-run-a-script-when-i-log-on-to-windows) via the task scheduler or registry in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` or Local Group Policy that performs something like `echo setCurrentUser("%USERNAME%"); > c:\your_project_directory\set-current-user.js`, then you just have a script that defines `<script>function setCurrentUser(s) { alert("Hello "+s); /* ... */ }</script>` followed by a script import like `<script src="set-current-user.js"></script>`

If you just want to be able to do whatever in the filesystem, change the shortcut that launches Chrome to `--allow-file-access-from-files --user-data-dir=c:\your_project_directory --disable-web-security` and restart the PC (or just kill all chrome.exe processes, incl. background).

*Edit: Updated with note on using --allow-file-access-from-files from Pritam Banerjee. If you go that route, he gets credit. :)*

If you're interested in trying NW.js, here's a full example:
[image: example package.json]
[image: example index.html]

`package.json` :

```json
{
  "name": "nw-hello-user",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "index.html"
}
```

`index.html` :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello!</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello <script>document.write(process.env.USERNAME)</script>!
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the command line:
[image: example command line]

Here's the end product!
[image: example screenshot]

Comment: `--allow-file-access-from-files` does not work on Chrome anymore. You will have to use : `--disable-web-security --user-data-dir`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, added to post, added mention. Up-voted.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged your question with PHP, you could just create a index.php file with the following contents:

```
Hi <?= getenv("USERNAME") ?>
```

`getenv("USERNAME")` returns the the value of the USERNAME environment variable.

**Update:** Thanks to TylerY86 for providing the more correct way to get the username. Also note from his comment below:

> You also have to be sure that the Apache instance is running in the
>   context of the user, and not as a service. If you try the example, if
>   you get something like SYSTEM or IUSR_MACHINE instead of the user
>   name, you'll need to adjust.

Comment: [``whoami``](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771299.aspx) outputs `domain\user` (where domain may be the computer name w/o a proper domain), you might want [`getenv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php)('USERNAME') to just get user, or [`get_current_user()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php) to be more direct (may still include domain).

Comment: Using PHP is the simplest solution to the problem here, *if it's installed as part of a WAMP package*.

Comment: @TylerY86 Thanks, I changed it to get_current_user(). I verified that it only gets the username part.

Comment: Up voted your answer. Fan of pedantically correct code and people that make the effort. :)

Comment: [Ah crap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548743/php-get-current-user-vs-execwhoami), you don't want `get_current_user`, like you said, it gets the owner of the script file... whoami and getenv would be better. You also have to be sure that the Apache instance is running in the context of the user, and not as a service. If you try the example, if you get something like `SYSTEM` or `IUSR_MACHINE` instead of the user name, you'll need to adjust.

Comment: @TylerY86 Thanks for checking on that. I updated my answer with that information.

Comment: If you have to run as a service, you might have to parse through the output of `\`qwinsta console\`` or `\`wmic computersystem get username /value\``.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices, as far as I see.

1) you may ask users to identify themself first time they use the page and store it to the local storage. Since those are different users on the machine, their localStorages should be separate.

2) You may deploy a small web service on the local host, that gets the user credentials from the system and returns on GET request.