# executing a script from a php file

Tags: php, exec

I have a php file which is called by a website:

example: serial_tx.php?v=W100

Within the php I write a log file where I can see which string v I received (W100 in this case).

The webserver is hosted on a Raspberry Pi and should send this data to the uart.

The files locations:

```
/SCRIPTS/serial_tx.php
/SCRIPTS/c/jmsend/serial_tx  // the executable, compiled from a C script
```

If I am in the root of the webserver and, from the console of my Pi, I run

```
sudo /var/www/html/SCRIPTS/c/jmsend/serial_tx W100
```

I get the command sent correctly.

With the php file I tried with system, shell_exec and exec without success.

```
shell_exec("sudo /var/www/html/SCRIPTS/c/jmsend/serial_tx ".$ric);
```

`$ric` is the received command.
I tried with different path settings too (starting from Pi root or webserver root).
All the files have a 777 as permissions.

Comment: Are you root when you execute the PHP? I'd guess PHP user can't execute `sudo`..or it is looking for a password prompt.

Comment: "All the files have a 777 as permissions." That's a rather poor idea. It's unlikely that whatever user the web server is running as will have permissions to access that directory and execute scripts within it, especially if `sudo` is not configured for passwordless use by that user. As well, always use `escapeshellargs()` to escape user input before dumping it onto your command line.

Comment: If I run whoami from the php file I get 'www-data' . How can I give this user sudo permissions?

Comment: Please check for understanding user concerns in PHP - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548743/php-get-current-user-vs-execwhoami. And as @miken32 mentioned it's not a good idea to give web server application rights for execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this in `/etc/sudoers` should work to allow your web server user to run that particular command without issue:

```
Cmnd_Alias SERIAL = /var/www/html/SCRIPTS/c/jmsend/serial_tx *
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: SERIAL
```

Note that you **must** [escape user input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) before using it:

```
$ric = escapeshellarg($_GET["v"]);
shell_exec("sudo /var/www/html/SCRIPTS/c/jmsend/serial_tx $ric");
```

You should also be aware of the differences between `exec()` and `shell_exec()`, specifically that you can't check for a failure using `shell_exec()`.

```
$ric = escapeshellarg($_GET["v"]);
exec("sudo /var/www/html/SCRIPTS/c/jmsend/serial_tx $ric", $output, $return);
if ($return !== 0) {
    // let the user know something didn't work
}
```

This assumes, of course, that your executable is written to return appropriate error codes.