# shell_exec("journalctl"); permissions

Tags: php, linux, centos

I'm trying to get log messages from journalctl from PHP, but getting an error - "Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
Users in the 'systemd-journal' group can see all messages."

```
shell_exec('whoami') //shows "admin"
```

Tried to put into /etc/sudoers.d/admin these lines one by one but none of them worked

```
%admin ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/journalctl
admin ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/journalctl
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

shell_exec("sudo -l"); - doesn't indicate that this privilege has been granted

How can I grant privilege to php shell_exec sudo on CENTOS 7 to get this request?

Comment: It depends if you run vom CLI or via webserver.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I run it from a web interface through a browser

Comment: Then you must grant access to the www-data user (default on apache).

Comment: @MarkusZeller it tried "www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" but surprisingly it didn't work. if I want only journalctl is it something like this "www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/journalctl -u mariadb -n"?

Comment: Look here for some details: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115054/php-shell-exec-permission-on-linux-ubuntu

Comment: @MarkusZeller thank you. But is it OK I get "admin" from running shell_exec('whoami')?

Comment: Also look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548743/php-get-current-user-vs-execwhoami

Comment: Check if SELinux is running. Look for any SELinux warning in /var/log/messages or /var/log/secure or /var/log/audit/audit.log

Comment: @MarkusZeller in my httpd.conf under User/Group I have "apache" and in phpinfo() under apache2handler I have "apache(48)/48". probably I need to use "apache ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/journalctl"?

Comment: @NirajNandane I have SELinux status: disabled

Comment: Then try adding `admin ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`

Comment: @NirajNandane thank you. it worked. I can see this line from shell_exec("sudo -l"). But I'm still getting an error from journalctl. I'll try to find out what's wrong with journalctl.

Comment: Can you please post here what error you see in journalctl?

Comment: @NirajNandane "Users in the 'systemd-journal' group can see all messages." tried changing "Storage=auto" to "Storage=persistent" on /etc/systemd/journald.conf. but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Add `admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` and `Defaults:admin !requiretty` in `/etc/sudoers` to get this working.

Comment: now it's working from SSH under admin, but doesn't work from shell_exec from php. I get same results running " id admin" 
"uid=1001(admin) gid=1001(admin) groups=1001(admin),190(systemd-journal)"  so it's some php shell_exec bug

Comment: Can you please try this `admin  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

Comment: Also try adding this in /etc/sudoers. `Defaults:admin !requiretty`